# SSRS Multiple Headers-Footers /Single List

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

[Example of Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54ahx.jpg)

I am fairly new to SSRS. 
I've been working on some reports and have come across a scenario that I'm not sure the best way to approach or if SSRS has a mechanism built in.

Any help or possible ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both to the header, then set visibility:

Hide pages 2 onwards:

```
=Globals!PageNumber=1
```

Hide page 1

```
=not Globals!PageNumber=1
```

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong. What you are saying is, add both of my desired headers to the "Header" then hide them based on which page is rendered?Do I need to set location to be correctly located at 0,0 when swapping from page 1 header to page 2 header?

Comment: This seems to be working as you described I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: Another question it appears that if I set a bunch of objects inside of a rectangle then move the rectangle the size of the rectangle is increased and leaves behind the children to the original position. Is there a way to affix the position of the children relative to the parent so that if i move the parent, the children objects stay relative to it?

Comment: @devSteve That means your objects did not land in the rectangle. Move them one at a time, make sure you don't drag them outside when adjusting their internal position

Comment: @johnmc The document outline says its contained within it. I've pretty much learned to not mess with drag and drop (pain in the ass). I use the document outline to grab the object and then use properties to set the values i need... But when i set the value of a rectangle it moves and all the children still stay there and the size of the rectangle just grows to continue holding the children. Using Visual Studio 2017